# What type of hardware do I need for a heavy fence gate?

Tags: fence, hardware

I am fencing in my back yard ('dog-ear' wooden picket fence) and am planning to make a large gate, say 10 ft wide, so that vehicles will be able to access the back yard if need be.

Specifically the fencing I will be buying is [this](http://www.lowes.com/pd_156652-77007-73000600_0__?productId=4331592&Ntt=dog+ear+wooden+fence&pl=1&currentURL=%3FNtt%3Ddog%2Bear%2Bwooden%2Bfence&facetInfo=). The gate itself will just be the same fence material, just raised off the ground and affixed with the proper "gate hardware" (hinges, handles, locks, etc.).

I am looking for the correct "gate hardware" that will be needed to make the gate functional as well as to be heavy-duty enough to support the weight of a 10 ft wide gate.

Features required:

- Hardware must support the weight of a 10 ft wide gate
- Hardware must allow the gate to swing one-way (to the outside)
- Hardware must provide a lockable handle mechanism so we can shut the gate and lock it (even if the lock mechanism is a separate unit altogether, such as a padlock)
- Inside outside openability (meaning I can open the gate from inside or outside the fence)
- Hardware must be black & metallic

I've never purchased anything like this before, and am hoping to find a [simple kit](http://www.lowes.com/pd_80488-1277-CD1308_0__?productId=1196777&Ntt=gate+hardware&pl=1&currentURL=%3FNtt%3Dgate%2Bhardware&facetInfo=) that does everything I need above, but doubt such a kit exists.

Any ideas as to what hardware I should be using, particularly for the size/weight of the gate?

Comment: Ignoring hardware, a 10' gate needs a lot of structure to function well. You might consider 2 - 5 foot wide gates, in order to keep the  requirements more modest. (The hardware to pin one gate closed so you can lock the other to it is called a "drop bolt".) Even so, you might look at welded box steel as the underpinning for those gates. The rest of the hardware you're asking about is in the gate hardware section at any big box store.

Comment: Just had one more thought: if your grade is even, you could carry the end of your 10' gate on a wheel (google "gate wheel"), which would mean you'd need a less substantial gate.

Comment: What kind of posts are you going to use on the hinge side?